# Sending canvas element over socket, maximum stack size in JS

Tags: javascript, html, socket.io, html5-canvas

I've got a following problem: I want to send canvas element over sockets using socket.io and Node.js. I've created below (pseudo)code:

```
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
// open sockets connection, join to the room etc.
socket.on('message', function(message) {
   alert(message.canvas);
});
$(myCanvas).mouseup(function(e) {
    socket.emit('message', {
         canvas: myCanvas,
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the second peer doesn't receive a message, first received this error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

from socket.io.js file, line 5380

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't emit a DOM element (your myCanvas).**

Socket.IO works by serializing whatever it's sending (largely using JSON serialization). But a canvas element cannot be serialized.

*You will have to serialize the canvas content* in order to emit it. For example, you could use  `myCanvas.toDataURL()` to create a dataURL (string) representing the canvas content.

Then on the listening side, you will:

- receive the dataURL,
- convert the dataURL into a new Image object,
- use `context.drawImage` to draw the new image object onto the receiver's canvas.